# How to apply a line break in mail body in Apple Mac?

Tags: excel, vba, macos, outlook

I have some experience in VBA for Windows but completely new to VBA for Apple MAC.

I can't figure out how to use the line break for the Mail Body part.

I tried vbCrLf, vbNewLine and HTML code. The whole thing coming in one single block. The code im using is given below.

```
Sub Mail_With_Outlook()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim Mail_Body As String
    
    Mail_Body = "Hi all," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                "This is line 1" & vbCrLf & _
                "This is line 2" & vbCrLf & _
                "This is line 3" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                "Regards" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                "Signature"

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    With wb
        MailFromMacwithOutlook bodycontent:=Mail_Body, _
                    mailsubject:="Whole workbook 1", _
                    toaddress:="Hilal175@gmail.com", _
                    ccaddress:="", _
                    bccaddress:="", _
                    attachment:="", _
                    displaymail:=True
    End With
    Set wb = Nothing

End Sub

Function MailFromMacwithOutlook(bodycontent As String, mailsubject As String, _
            toaddress As String, ccaddress As String, bccaddress As String, _
            attachment As String, displaymail As Boolean)

    Dim scriptToRun As String

    scriptToRun = scriptToRun & "tell application " & _
                  Chr(34) & "Microsoft Outlook" & Chr(34) & Chr(13)

    scriptToRun = scriptToRun & _
      "set NewMail to make new outgoing message with properties" & _
      "{content:""" & bodycontent & """, subject:""" & mailsubject & """}" & Chr(13)

    If toaddress <> "" Then scriptToRun = scriptToRun & _
      "make new to recipient at NewMail with properties" & _
      "{email address:{address:""" & toaddress & """}}" & Chr(13)

    If ccaddress <> "" Then scriptToRun = scriptToRun & _
      "make new cc recipient at NewMail with properties" & _
      "{email address:{address:""" & ccaddress & """}}" & Chr(13)

    If bccaddress <> "" Then scriptToRun = scriptToRun & _
      "make new bcc recipient at NewMail with properties" & _
      "{email address:{address:""" & bccaddress & """}}" & Chr(13)

    If attachment <> "" Then
        scriptToRun = scriptToRun & "make new attachment at NewMail with properties" & _
          "{file:""" & attachment & """ as alias}" & Chr(13)
    End If

    If displaymail = False Then
        scriptToRun = scriptToRun & "send NewMail" & Chr(13)
    Else
        scriptToRun = scriptToRun & "open NewMail" & Chr(13)
    End If
    scriptToRun = scriptToRun & "end tell" & Chr(13)
    
    MacScript (scriptToRun)
   
End Function
```

Comment: Ok. Found the answer. Need to use Chr(10) instead vbCrLf . will do the job. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Found the answer. Need to use Chr(10) instead vbCrLf . will do the job. Thank you